# async function returns Promise <Pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, async-await

i'm building a crud app for a project,
people can add view and delete entries, i'm using nodejs, js and fireabse for this.
i have such a firestore database structure:

```
entries:
   --entry id
      --entry data
users:
   --user id
      --user email (query)
      -- my entries (collection)
           -- entries id
              --entry id
```

now i want to display all users entries,
so i created this module.exports function:

```
module.exports = {  
  //get all the users entries from database with passed in uid ('/dashboard')
  getUserEntries: async uid => {
    //get all his entries docs id from "myEntries" collection in an, array
    const usersEntriesId = await db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("myEntries")
      .get()
      .then(entries => {
        return entries.docs.map(entry => entry.data().entry);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(usersEntriesId); //works fine, logs array with ids

    const userEntriesDocs = usersEntriesId.map(async id => {
      const entry = await db
        .collection("entries")
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then(entry => {
          return entry.data();
        });
      console.log("hello:", entry); //works fine returns logs entry data

      return entry;
    });

    console.log("hello1: ", userEntriesDocs); //doesnt work i get "hello1:  [ Promise { <pending> },
 // Promise { <pending> },
  //Promise { <pending> } ]"
//i got three entries, that's why i get 3 times "Promise { <pending> }"
  }
};
```

so how do i resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. If you want the value a promise resolves to, await it or use .then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, `async` function returns `Promise`, it how they works under the hood. If there was no `.map` you could just `await` on that function or use it as arbitrary `Promise` with `.then()` and `.catch`. But since there is array of `Promise` you need [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all are resolved.

```
const userEntriesDocs = await Promise.all(usersEntriesId.map(async id => {
....
);
```

Beware: unlike [`.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), `.all()` will fail immediately if any of subsequent `Promise` fails. So if for any reason you want to have data from those requests that succeeded, you need more complex logic.

As an alternative you may go through loop manually:

```
const userEntriesDocs = [];
for(const docPromise of userEntriesId.map(.....)) {
  userEntriesDocs.push(await docPromise);
}
```

But to me `await Promise.all[...]` is more readable.

Also I highlight there is array of Promises(requests have already been sent). If you try sending requests *inside the loop* like

```
const userEntriesDocs = [];
for(const id of userEntriesId) {
  userEntriesDocs.push(await db
        .collection("entries")
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then(entry => {
          return entry.data();
         })
  );
}
```

you will find that requests are going strictly one-by-one, not in parallel. That will require much more time to process the list.

Comment: I think you're missing `await` before your `Promise.all()`. Without that, `userEntriesDocs` is a promise itself.

Comment: yeah, thanks both of you, so if i have a few promises in one function i need to use Promise.all()? is it possible to achieve it with more async await lines?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld only alternative is to use loop and `await` inside of it. I've add sample on that appraoch.